# passing props to children missing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to pass props down to children?

```
const Tabs = ({ children, props }) => {
  console.log(props) //where is activeTab??
  return React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { ...props })
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs activeTab={1}>
      <div>tabs children</div>
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

expecting props is an object where is has activeTab equal to 1 but above code gave me undefined?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vnz4z84vq7

Comment: Use `const Tabs = ({ children, ...props }) => {`...
or `const Tabs = ({ children, activeTab }) => {`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need destructuring here. Just accept `props` as argument like this

```
const Tabs = ( props ) => {
// ... props.children - is your children object
}
```

If you want to use destructuring it would be like this

```
const Tabs = ( {children, activeTab } ) => {
// now children and activeTab is passed props
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `activeTab` and `children` will be passed to your component as properties of `props` parameter, so to access them just change your component to:

```
const Tabs = (props) => {
  console.log(props.activeTab);
  console.log(props.children);
  return React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { ...props })
  )
}
```

or if you want to destructure you can write

```
const Tabs = ({ children, activeTab, ...props }) => { 
   console.log(activeTab);
   console.log(children);
   return React.Children.map(children, child =>
     React.cloneElement(child, { ...props })
   )
}
```